# mat-form-field prefix & suffix location with buttons

Tags: css, angular, prefix, suffix, mat-form-field

I'm trying to build a list of inputs with +/- buttons at the edges of each one.
I'm using Angular Material with mat-form-field prefix & suffix, and it works fine on a single input, but not when multiply (whether by ngFor or a simple html copy-paste).

This is how the inputs should looks like:
[inputs look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8141t.png)

This is how each input should look like when hovered:
[input hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY1Gu.png)

And this is the bug I'm trying to fix - in some of the inputs (as far as I can see, totally by random) the buttons go up a little bit, like so (hovered so its easier to see) :
[input with bug - buttons location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB7am.png)

Full code here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-pre-su-fix-btns?file=src/app/form-field-appearance-example.scss

Comment: So unfortunately not an answer but, using element inspection and changing the css for `.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline { top: .25em; //Disable this }` you can fix the positional problems of the elements that currently are too high up, but it makes some buttons align too far down, whereas others it doesn't affect all. The auto generated css seems to be at fault (elements alignment in regards to each other), but i can't tell why, and it's kinda a mess to go through... maybe this can at least help you/someone else towards a proper answer.

Comment: First of all - thank you for your time trying to figure it out :) 
The .25em is the default value, I've tried overriding it (added to the code in the link) and it still didn't change...

Comment: same problem here. dont know why that extra top location is there. works only in inspect mode